# SonarQube Execution Failure Cannot find the assembly

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2

I've been searching everywhere for a solution to this error but have not been lucky to find one so far. Would anyone happen to know how to resolve this issue?

> INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>
> INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Total time: 9.118s
>
> Final Memory: 27M/513M
>
> INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>
> ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
>
> ERROR: Caused by: Cannot find the assembly 
>   "e:\Builds\52\IT\QLMSFileSystemPurge.Nightly\src..\bin\Rock.QL.QLMSClientPortal.Services.FileSystemPurge.exe" provided by the property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly".
>
> ERROR:
>
> ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
>
> ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild to analyze your C# projects as documented on http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/bAAW. It has native support for FxCop, and FxCop will be executed during the build by MSBuild, with the right settings.

Setting the `sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly` either directly or indirectly through the Visual Studio Bootstrapper plugin is no longer supported.